# Count marked/selected records/rows in access table

Tags: ms-access, vba, office365, copy-paste

I need an option where I can select a range of records or rows in an access table or access query [(see this screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8Xos.png) and then have something to tell me how many records I have actually selected.

When working with copy & paste, this is a very helpful feature, if you work with big data tables. I have searched long and hard but no-one seems to be providing a solution by manually selecting with your cursor.

Does anyone know any solution to this? (maybe implementing a vba macro?)

---

**A little bit of background information:**

My co-worker used to work with an excel file and got very used to the functionalities of excel. As time went on the excel file became bigger and bigger -  by now it takes approximately two minutes to start up the excel file.

He hit me up and asked me if I knew a clever solution for him - so I thought MS Access would be the perfect software for him.

Since he's going to work with copy & paste it's necessary to know how many records he has copied - so that he knows how many records he needs to select to paste the copied records (access isn't as flexible as excel when it comes to using copy & paste).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Form property* `SelHeight` returns the count of selected records.

Comment: I read that too, but isn't that just to use in an access form? And how do I implement this property in my code?

Comment: You have posted no code, so hard to tell, but just refer to the form and the property where you need it.

Comment: Thank you @Gustav - I didn't understand that a form can be a query or a table. I thought that by the term form it was literally meant a ms access form.

Comment: True. However, a form may hold a recordset(clone), but that doesn't make it neither a table nor a query.